# Windows Installation Errors

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, hard-drive, boot, windows-installation

Since yesterday I have been trying to install Windows on a Laptop I have. It used to have it, but for some reason when I booted up, it wouldn't boot, and it wasn't recognizing the hard drive.

I replaced it and tried re-installing Windows 7, and everything goes well, until l it reboots and says Some files are corrupt, or some specific driver is missing, or there is a hardware error. The specific error was, 0xc00000e9.

I tried different installation disks, and that didn't work, then I tried switching out the dvd drive for another one, didn't work. And then I switched the hard drives, and It didn't work. All the hard drives I tried were working, and the Disks I knew were for sure working too.

Now, I tried installing Win7 on a new hdd, and it says Some installation files are missing, and it cancels the install. Same problem.
Then, I tried installing Windows XP, and it all goes good until reboot, and it says it can't start because some file is missing or corrupt, such as (ntoskrnl.exe) But a lot of the time there are others that it says are missing too.

I have no idea what could be causing this, maybe could it be the RAM or something?

***EDIT*** After some tries, I successfully installed Windows Xp, and it works, but now When i try to install windows 7 from inside it, it did not work, and when I try the normal Installation again, it says windows cannot install the required files because they may be corrupt or missing, error 0x80070017.

Answer (score 0):

A few years ago I had the same issue with a desktop while installing Windows XP.
Though my case was a bit different because some times it would 'crash' while installing and some times I had no error at all.
At some point it all worked again, but I never knew why.
However, I did some extra steps beside what you already tried.
    - Cleaned all the dust from the computer case
    - Reseated all connectors in the case (also all cards).
    - Changed my monitor (after I did this (beside other things) it worked, maybe the monitor driver was missing).
    - Swapped memory slots between already seated memory (I had no backup memory).
    - Turned off the power and held the on button pressed for 10 seconds to make sure there was no power on/in the case.
    - Created a new installation image using NLite.

In the end, I was able to use the NLite image with most of the drivers for my hardware present on it. After this I had no problems any more.

I know my answer may be a bit vague, but at least you could try some of these options.

Another thing may be to upgrade your BIOS version to the newest version to be sure there are no bugs on the initializing of disks and other hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Please test the RAM by using `memtest`. I had a similar problem , checked the RAM and it failed the tests. If this is your case, changing the RAM fixed the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried to install on a external HDD? Might be your SATA chipset has some problem?

Comment: I could Try that, But i would prefer not to. But In the past, I had successfully installed windows 7 on this laptop, and it all worked okay, but Recently using it, the old drive had gone bad, and Now I can't install anything to it without getting errors. I may Try installing to an external though, thanks for the input!